# Multiple Wordpress Child Themes

Tags: wordpress

I have a quick question:

Is it possible to have multiple child themes activated at once? I need to have many different page templates activate at once. If it's not possible how can I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. However, you can setup custom page layouts and if you need to define them differently (say background is different on each) use a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.
What you can maybe do is coding different stylesheets that you use depending on your needs. You can manage them in the php code and even switch them in javascript easily.

Answer (score 0):

To activate multiple themes/child themes, you simply cannot. But you can show different layout to your visitor just by only using one theme. What do you mean by to activate many different template at once? Are you referring to how the page will going to be displayed?